# Auto add analytics multidomain tracking to links

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, mootools

i'm trying to add a script in mootools (joomla's default) to change the onclick event on the links that point to the domains i'm tracking.

I've tried this:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
  $$('a[href^=http://mydomain.com]').addEvents({
    click: function(){ 
        try {
            if(_gaq) {
        alert('hola');
        _gaq.push(['_link', "'" + this.getProperty('href') + "'"]); 
        return false;
            }
        }
        catch (err) {}
    }
    });
});
```

but it is not sending correctly the cookie info in the url to mydomain.com.

Thank you.

Comment: what 'cookie' info are you referring to?

Comment: the gal info that is stored in the cookie for tracking should be passed to  'mydomain' by the _gaq.push _link method

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
_gaq.push(['_link', this.getProperty('href')]);
```

Also, [Google Analytics isn't a real time tracker](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Analytics/thread?tid=66b00c4cf7eb7970&hl=en). It takes up to 24 hours see them in your report.

Comment: actually, it is real time now. your change is superfluous, i don't think it will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this MooTools tracker class that tracks downloads, mail links and outbound links.
It should fit you like a glove

https://gist.github.com/1480885